# Adicionar linhas em um determinado lugar do TMemo

Tags: delphi

Possuo alguns variáveis que recebem alguns dados de um edit comum.
Minha duvida é a seguinte, a pessoa vai clicar no botão e *TMemo* vai receber os dados, gostaria que nessa ação ele limpasse os mesmo edit e repetir o processo quantas vezes necessário, porem eu preciso inserir esses dados no meio do *Tmemo*, como o exemplo a baixo:

```
    Memo1.Lines.Add(var1); #linha adicionada ao clicar no botão.
    Memo1.Lines.Add('linha adicionada'); # essa linha deve ser adicionada após a
    anterior quando o usuário clicar no mesmo botão.
    Memo1.Lines.Add('linha adicionada2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o seguinte comanda para escrever em determinada linha do `TMemo`:

```
Memo1.Lines[3] := 'asd';
```

Ou você pode fazer assim também:

```
Memo1.Lines.Insert(3, 'asd');
```

Caso precise deletar uma linha em especifico use:

```
Memo1.Lines.Delete(3);
```

Comment: Interessante sua resposta, ajudou bastante.
Talvez você possa me ajudar sou novo nisso ainda.
Estou escrevendo na linha 9 e 10. gostaria de quando ele apertasse o botão novamente ele escrevesse na 11 e 12 e assim por diante. é possível?